# CSS Navigation Item Being Pushed Right

Tags: css, margin, padding

I'm trying to work on a layout and I have an issue with the navigation. If you look on the Codepen posted below and hover over the 'Home' link in the navigation, the drop-down menu will appear and it will push the other main links to the left. What is causing this and how can I fix it? I've been messing with it for a couple hours and I'm lost. Thanks for any help.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Cmcyr

Comment: I didn't delete it. Dx, sorry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no width being set on the `a`, `ul` or `li`s, so when the `ul` is displayed, the parent is expanding to the width of its widest child.

Remove the horizontal padding from the `li`s and set `text-align: center;` and give them or their parent (`ul`) a max-width the same size or narrower than its parent (`a`).